# If I want to define a container (from the STL) of elements from a type "T" so "T" must a default constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I read that if I want to define array of elements from a type `T` , so `class T` must a default c'tor (It's correct, yes?).

But what about defining container (from the STL) of elements from type `T`?

Comment: You could try it and see if it works...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes I know, but I want explanation about that.

Comment: @Software_t, each container and its member functions impose different constraints on `T`. This is not a good place to address all of them.

Comment: @R Sahu I don't believe any Standard Library containers require the values they store to be default constructible.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, DefaultConstructible is referenced in lots of places in the C++11 Standard. I, obviously, didn't do a thorough check of how many of those are related to containers (or specific member functions of containers). `map::operator[]` requires the `mapped_type` to be DefaultConstructible. I suspect there are other container member functions that require `T` to be DefaultConstructible but I don't have a comprehensive list.

Comment: @R Sahu Oh, yes, I forgot about map - my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need default constructors in both cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    int x;
    A(int x) : x(x) {}
};

int main()
{
    A arr[3] {A(0), A(1), A(2)}; // An array

    std::vector<A> vec; // A std container
    vec.push_back(A(0));
    vec.push_back(A(1));
    vec.push_back(A(2));
}
```

Though, for some containers the lack of default constructor disables some operations, like [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: But you will need a copy c'tor, yes?

Comment: @Software_t Open the description of your favorite container on https://en.cppreference.com/ ([here's the link for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)), look for requirements for element types.